# Vue 3 function that returns src

Tags: image, vue.js

I have this vue function. That should return the img srs, dynamically. For some reasons, it is not reading the string as a local file. Image is not showing.

```
script 

 showSuccessPercentage(recieved) {
      if (typeof recieved === "object" && recieved != null) {

        if(recieved["successRunsPercentage"] > 50) {
          return "'../assets/img/rainy.png'"
        }
              } 
      else return "N/A";
      
    },
```

HTML

```
<img class= "w-10" :src="showSuccessPercentage(currentView.worstReport) " alt="Organization Icon" />
```

looks simple. Not sure why it's giving me a hard time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `require` method to get the local image render in Vue.app.

```
showSuccessPercentage(recieved) {
    if (typeof recieved === "object" && recieved != null) {

      if (recieved["successRunsPercentage"] > 50) {
        return require('../assets/img/rainy.png')
      }
    } 
    else return "N/A";
  },
```

Comment: I tried, but no. It's not working. Any other guide?

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes it worked with required. Not sure why it didn't the first time....Really thank you !